# Create a stuck thread (Weblogic)(J2SE)(1.5)

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

I need to test WLST script that checks for stuck threads across some managed instances on a weblogic deployment. Unfortunately when I need to test, I am unable to get my stuck thread problem to rear its head. How can I intentionally create a stuck thread to test my script's detection with? My thoughts presently have been to sleep a thread for more than my stuck thread limit on Weblogic's settings, but that is also longer than the timeout for webpages. So my request should timeout before the thread ever becomes stuck. Apache commons executor is another idea... Does anyone have an elegant solution to reproducing this ugly issue?

Comment: Please define the exact behavior you need to reproduce.

Comment: When I poll for threads for a given runtime with something like `get("domainRuntime:/ServerRuntimes/server1/ThreadPoolRuntime/ThreadPoolRuntime/ExecuteThreads")` and iterates through the threads, I need to find some that the `thread.isStuck()` returns true

Comment: Stuck is an attribute determined by WebLogic when a thread has worked continuously past a preset amount of time that is specified in the "overload" tab

Comment: Can you create a thread that works continuously past that preset amount?  Sounds like looking at the wall clock to see to do more work should be a reasonable approach.  System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: That might work, but I didn't want to max out my processor and the system is very good at optomizing repetitive mundane tasks. John's answer of locking the thread and never notifiying it worked well because the thread appears to still be working when it is waiting on a lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a stuck thread you can simply suspend it

```
synchronized(this){
   wait();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never create threads in a Java EE environment, it's forbidden by the specification. If your apps are doing this, you'll always have problems.

Anyway, a "stuck thread" is a little ambiguous. You can you put in into an infinite loop:

```
while(true){
 try{
  Thread.sleep(1000);
 } catch (Exception e){
  break;
 }
}
```

or you could lock it on a monitor:

```
while (true){
 new Object().wait();
}
```